# How to make a multi axis graph with Gnuplot 5.2?

Tags: linux, graph, gnuplot

I've this data :

```
2019-11-11;/dev/hd1/;10
2019-11-11;/dev/hd2/;12
2019-11-11;/dev/hd3/;14
2019-11-11;/dev/hd4/;16
2019-11-11;/dev/hd5/;18
2019-11-11;/dev/hd6/;20
2019-11-12;/dev/hd1/;13
2019-11-12;/dev/hd2/;15
2019-11-12;/dev/hd3/;17
2019-11-12;/dev/hd4/;19
2019-11-12;/dev/hd5/;21
2019-11-12;/dev/hd6/;23
2019-11-13;/dev/hd1/;16
2019-11-13;/dev/hd2/;19
2019-11-13;/dev/hd3/;21
2019-11-13;/dev/hd4/;24
2019-11-13;/dev/hd5/;23
2019-11-13;/dev/hd6/;26
```

I'm able to make a multi axis graph with excel :

[image]

But when I try to do it with Gnuplot 5.2, I don't make it...

Can you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

People here expect that you show some code and your effort to solve your problem, however, I assume you are a gnuplot beginner and I have to admit that your desired plot from the provided data is not straightforward with gnuplot (unless there is a simpler way which hasn't come to my mind.) 
I would loop the data and filter it by a function using the ternary operator. There is certainly room for improvements. 
Check `help ternary`, `help timecolumn` as well as the other keywords for more detailed information.

**Code:**

```
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2019-11-11;/dev/hd1/;10
2019-11-11;/dev/hd2/;12
2019-11-11;/dev/hd3/;14
2019-11-11;/dev/hd4/;16
2019-11-11;/dev/hd5/;18
2019-11-11;/dev/hd6/;20
2019-11-12;/dev/hd1/;13
2019-11-12;/dev/hd2/;15
2019-11-12;/dev/hd3/;17
2019-11-12;/dev/hd4/;19
2019-11-12;/dev/hd5/;21
2019-11-12;/dev/hd6/;23
2019-11-13;/dev/hd1/;16
2019-11-13;/dev/hd2/;19
2019-11-13;/dev/hd3/;21
2019-11-13;/dev/hd4/;24
2019-11-13;/dev/hd5/;23
2019-11-13;/dev/hd6/;26
EOD

set colorsequence classic
set datafile separator ";"
set datafile missing NaN
myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set timefmt myTimeFmt

set xdata time
set xtics 3600*24           # one tic per day
set format x "%d.%m.%Y"
set xrange["2019-11-10 20:00":"2019-11-13 04:00"]
set yrange[8:28]
set ytics 5
set grid ytics
set key top left

myFilter(c,n) = strcol(c)[8:8] == n ? $3 : NaN

plot \
     for [i=1:6] $Data u (timecolumn(1)):(myFilter(2,i)) w lp pt 7 title sprintf("/dev/hd%d/",i), \
     for [i=1:6] $Data u (timecolumn(1)):(myFilter(2,i)):3 w labels offset 0,0.7 notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]